# 403 Forbidden Error | IIS 10.0 | Fails if content-length > 102400

Tags: c#, rest, iis, http-status-code-403, iis-10

I have an asmx based web service deployed on Windows IIS 10.0. It's working perfectly fine till the request content length is less that `1,02,400`.

It shows `403 forbidden error` when I provide request with content length greater than `102400`.

I am pretty sure there is some configuration limiting large request headers. Not sure which one as I already have configured below parameters.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :**

**Failed Request Tracing -**
[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2 -
After Removing Redirect Custom Error Page**

[image]

**Solution -**

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Learn which module gives 403 first.

Comment: @LexLi Can you please elaborate? I don't find a trace of 403 in the link provided.

Comment: It shows how to troubleshoot 404.2, but you can apply the same to 403.

Comment: try to set the Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)  by using iis request filtering feature. Select Requests Filtering and open it by double-clicking the icon.
From the Actions pane on the right hand side of the screen click Edit Feature Settings.https://i.postimg.cc/dQ8RYb7D/2803.jpg

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Nope. it's the same value as yours in the screenshot.

Comment: @LexLi updated the question with failed request tracing results. But still it didn't lead me to anything. Any help?

Comment: Then clearly 403.18 is the thing you should chase after now, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 And that's why FRT is just the start.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for guiding in the right direction. You are right. I was redirecting to error page. I removed that. But now it is 500 - internal server error.

Comment: 500.0 is usually caused by unhandled exceptions in your application code. Time to do some debugging there.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for guiding me through. It was actually throwing an error from the core code itself. Fixed it. Learnt the generic error tracing for any error through the process. Thanks a lot.